# How to perform deep Q-learning batch update step on a neural network with multiple outputs

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am taking on deep Q-learning and I am stuck at understanding one particular thing. I have googled multiple deep Q-learning examples, but literally everyone posting tutorials uses a cart-pole game to present the algorithm and this game does not encounter similar issues to my problem.

The original Deepmind's Volodymyr Mnih's paper (https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) states the algorithm as follows:

[image: The algorithm]

I do not understand the part where $y_j$ is set.

In my problem, my Q function is an ANN with 64 inputs, one hidden layer of 48 neurons and 8 outputs. Each output represents an action (= I assume there are 8 actions available).

How do I set the $y_j$ however? Let's say I evaluate a state $s_{j+1}$ with my model Q and my output looks like this: $\begin{bmatrix} 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.1\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore $\text{max}_{a'}Q(s_{j+1},a';\theta) = 1$ (first element of the vector is indexed with 0).

State $s_{j+1}$ is non-terminal and current observed reward $r_j$ is 1. How do I set $y_j$? It should be of length 8, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my problem, my Q function is an ANN with 64 inputs, one hidden layer of 48 neurons and 8 outputs. Each output represents an action (= I assume there are 8 actions available).
>
> How do I set the $y_j$ however? Let's say I evaluate a state $s_{j+1}$ with my model Q and my output looks like this: $\begin{bmatrix} 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.1\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore $\text{max}_{a'}Q(s_{j+1},a';\theta) = 1$ (first element of the vector is indexed with 0).

That seems wrong, are you confusing max with argmax? $\text{max}_{a'}Q(\phi_{j+1},a';\theta) = 0.4$ in your example, using the notation of storing $\phi_{j+1} = \phi(s_{j+1})$ to match the pseudo-code (although you *can* use $s$ and $\phi$ almost interchangeably throughout in this case, $\phi_j$ is just the NN's input representation for $s_j$).

Looks like the document you are using also confuses max with argmax when setting $a_t$ - in that case it should be an argmax.

> State $s_{j+1}$ is non-terminal and current observed reward $r_j$ is 1. How do I set $y_j$? It should be of length 8, am I right?

Your training vector needs to be of length 8, but it is only *related* to $y_j$, it is not the same as it. $y_j$ is the estimate for the target of a single $Q(\phi_j, a_j)$ value, whilst your network outputs 8 different action values $\begin{bmatrix} Q(\phi_j, a_0) & Q(\phi_j, a_1) & Q(\phi_j, a_2) & . . . \end{bmatrix}$. The Q-learning algorithm itself is not designed around the structure of neural networks (or any specific approximator). Instead you have to make the neural network training fit to what Q-learning does.

$y_j = 1 + 0.9 * 0.4 = 1.36$ assuming $\gamma = 0.9$ and the non-terminal result as you said. It is a single scalar value, and it relates to the target output for $a_j$ only. The other 7 target values in your vector, you do not have training values for . . .

So, you know nothing about the actions that were not taken. You have two basic choices:

- Alter the loss function or gradient calculations so that the only important output for training purposes is that for $a_j$. Assuming $a_j$ was 5 for instance then your training target could then be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.36 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Whether or not you can do this depends on your NN framework, but this would be the most efficient approach.
- Run the network forward for $Q(\phi_j, *)$ to get the current output vector, and adjust the value of just $a_j$ output to equal $y_j$ for training. Again assuming $a_j$ was 5 for instance, and that you ran the network forward to get the outputs $\begin{bmatrix} 1.1 & 2.1 & 1.5 & 0.3 & 0.9 & 1.7 & 1.3 & 1.4\end{bmatrix}$ training target could then be $\begin{bmatrix}1.1 & 2.1 & 1.5 & 0.3 & 0.9 & 1.36 & 1.3 & 1.4\end{bmatrix}$. This has the advantage of being simple to drop in to standard NN frameworks whilst not messing around with custom loss functions or gradient functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, $y_j$ is not a vector of length 8. It is a single value.

> $y_j$ describes the Q-value that agent has got by performing action $a_t$
>   in the state $s_t$.

**Note : If you only want answer of your question, you can directly look at the last part of the answer. I've written initial part for explaining Deep Q Leaning algorithm.**

So, to describe the entire scenario,

Agent is currently in state $s_t$ (State $s_t$ is one of many combinations possible from your 64 input neurons). Now Agent has to select an action from given state $s_t$. Here the situation is called explore-exploit dilemma. By selecting exploitation, Agent chooses best action it has learnt, and by choosing exploration, Agent randomly pick any action out of 8 possible actions. This action is $a_t$. By performing this action $a_t$ in a state $s_t$, Agent receives a reward $r_t$ from the environment and moves to the next step $s_t$$_+$$_1$. This is one step of RL process.

Now, based on this move we need to update Q-value. $y_t$ is the Q-value as mentioned earlier,  which stores Q-value of the action $a_t$ in state $s_t$. We are using Bellman equation for updating Q-value.

As shown in the algorithm, if next state(means $s_t$$_+$$_1$) is a terminal state than Q-value is simply the environment reward $r_t$. But if it is a non-terminal state, then **according to Bellman equation, we need to choose best action from all the possible actions in next state $s_t$$_+$$_1$**(This is the meaning of that equation). For doing this, we need to supply state $s_t$$_+$$_1$ as the input in ANN ($s_t$$_+$$_1$ is again one of many combinations possible from your 64 input neurons), ANN will give values for all 8 actions, we need to pick highest value from those 8 values. Then multiply this highest value with discount factor gamma. And finally add environment reward $r_t$ in it. This gives the value for $y_t$ for non-terminal state. Remember this Q-value $y_t$ is for only the action $a_t$ in state $s_t$, and it is a single value, not a vector.

So, Finally to answer your question,

You have Q-values of all the 8 actions from state $s_t$$_+$$_1$ , which are

> `[0.2 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.1]`

As per the Bellman equation, pick highest value, which is 0.4.

So,

> $y_j$ = $r_j$ + gamma * $\text{max}_{a'}Q(s_{j+1},a';\theta)$
>
> $y_j$ = 1 + gamma * 0.4     (gamma value of your choice such that 0= <
>   gamma <= 1)

**Note : Please treat $y_j$ and $y_t$ same throughout the answer.**

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply. It has helped me in understanding. But having $y_j$ as a single value, I am now confused with performing the gradient descent. My ANN representing the Q function should then be a different ANN than the one which selects the action? I thought it is the same one.
So I have to have a separate ANN which will take state and action as inputs and outputs single number representing the Q value?

Comment: My initial idea was to train the model on the minibatch sampled from my replay memory as follows (using Keras, but one can treat the following line as a pseudocode as well): `model.fit(states, targets)` where `target` is $y_j$. I guess this is really not the way to go.

Comment: When we give state $s_t$ as an input in ANN, it gives Q-values of all possible 8 actions. We select any one action $a_t$(using exploration/exploitation) out of 8 possible actions. And now for the chosen action $a_t$, we calculate theoretical Q-value(Using Bellman equation). So, gradient descent calculates loss. So, loss is calculated based for action $a_t$ only, for all the other actions we take loss as 0, because that action isn't selected.So, loss is  MSE between $y_j$ and actual Q-value for that action(O/P of ANN). Network is update using this loss only, for all remaining actions loss is 0.

Comment: As the answer of your first comment, only one ANN is enough to do this.  ANN will take only states as the I/P and will O/P Q-values of all actions.

Comment: I give you one example  for clearing your doubt. Suppose for I/P state $s_t$, we got following output from ANN, which is Q-values of all actions [0.2 0.4 0.2 **0.1** 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.1]. Now, suppose action 3 is selected (Q-value 0.1). We calculate $y_t$ for this action as mentioned in the answer, suppose that value is 1.2. So, for this state your expected O/P is [0.2 0.4 0.2 **1.2** 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.1], and you got [0.2 0.4 0.2 **0.1** 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.1] from ANN. model.train_on_batch(ip, trgt)/model.fit(ip/trgt) calculates MSE between this two vectors internally and update the ANN network.

Comment: Thank you very much, the comments actually explained what I meant with my question! To spare other using to go through the comments, I have to accept @Neil-Slater 's answer which also gives the answer I aws looking for. Thank you again for your quick and helpful replies!

Comment: Just wanted to share knowledge. Glad to help you.